# Compiling ASP.NET application - Web Site vs Web Application - Placeholder aspx file with specified dll names

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

An ASP.NET application was developed outside of Visual Studio and contains one aspx (pv.aspx) file which has both the ASP.NET code as well as the Visual Basic code.  Originally, we compiled the aspx file using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method.  This created a aspx "placeholder" file, thereby hiding all of the ASP as well as the vb code contained in the file.  However, one part that was not desirable was the naming of the .dll files (ex: "pv.aspx.cdcab7d2.compiled").

I then attempted to create a web site project inside of VS2010 following what [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/08/21/compiling-and-deploying-asp-net-applications.aspx) person was explaining but in that case, the VB code was compiled correctly yet the ASP.NET code was not compiled and still visible (i.e. not a placeholder file as when compiled using aspnet_compiler.exe).

While both options do work and the application runs smoothly in IIS, it is not what the client wants.  I have been directed to do the following things:

- Compile pv.aspx to a placeholder file in the same way aspnet_compiler.exe does from the command line
- Compile the dll file to have a specific name such as pv.dll

I have found information on StackOverflow and other sites to do one thing or the other but not both.  Is it even possible?  If not, how could I design this web application so that the asp.net code as well as the vb code can't be seen but the dll files still have a specified name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Visual Studio 2010, publishing the Web Application in release mode would create the place holder files. If you want to set up some conditional compilation options, you can set them under the build tab in the WebProject properties. As for setting the  fixed name for the assembly refer to this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx#PreCompilingToFixedNameAssemblies

look for Precompiling to Fixed-Name Assemblies, Precompiling to Signed Assemblies

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The first option you want (compiling to a placeholder) is a function of the [ASP.NET compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229863%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), specifically with the `-u` flag not set.  The files names that come out of the compiler are generated internally and are largely not configurable.  The only option that the compiler exposes regarding naming is `-fixednames`, which will compile each page and control to a its own DLL file; the default behavior is to batch them as the compiler sees fit.  You still have no control over the naming.  (If you use the [ASP.NET merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397866%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tool, which can combine multiple DLLs into one, you'll have some control of the name for DLL files.)

The .compiled files, with the undesirable names, are not DLL files and are necessary in order to locate the correct assembly and entry point when loading each page.  From [File Handling During ASP.NET Precompilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e22s60h9%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> .compiled Files
>
> For executable files in an ASP.NET Web application, the compiler assemblies and files with the .compiled file name extension. The assembly name is generated by the compiler. The .compiled file does not contain executable code. Instead, it contains only the information that ASP.NET needs to find the appropriate assembly.
>
> After the precompiled application is deployed, ASP.NET uses the assemblies in the Bin folder to process requests. The precompilation output includes .aspx or .asmx files as placeholders for pages. The placeholder files contain no code. They exist only to provide a way to invoke ASP.NET for a specific page request and so that file permissions can be set to restrict access to the pages.